# Cannot set global variable with dolist in Elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to exclude modes that don't need `show-trailing-whitespace`:

```
(set-default 'show-trailing-whitespace t)

(defmacro non-trailing-whitespaces-modes (mode)
  (let ((hook (intern (concat  (symbol-name mode) "-mode-hook"))))
    `(add-hook ',hook (lambda () (setq show-trailing-whitespace nil)))))

(defvar trailing-whitespace-exclude-modes '(eshell term help diff ztree org calendar syslog slime-repl Info ielm))

(dolist (m trailing-whitespace-exclude-modes)
  (non-trailing-whitespaces-modes m))
```

However, I cannot add hook using `dolist`, but adding idividual call for each mode works, for example:

```
(non-trailing-whitespaces-modes eshell)
(non-trailing-whitespaces-modes term)
(non-trailing-whitespaces-modes ielm
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

```lisp
(macroexpand '(non-trailing-whitespaces-modes m))
;; (add-hook (quote m-mode-hook)
;;           (lambda nil (setq show-trailing-whitespace nil)))
```

Your task does not really require you to use macros.
Turn your macro into a function and you're done.

Here's the equivalent defun that can be used in `dolist`:

```lisp
(defun non-trailing-whitespaces-modes (mode)
  (let ((hook (intern (concat (symbol-name mode) "-mode-hook"))))
    (add-hook hook (lambda () (setq show-trailing-whitespace nil)))))
```

Comment: I see. Macro takes argument symbol as it is. Well, at least I know more about macro. Also, by turning into a function, do you mean that I should create a list of hooks and add function to those hooks? If this is the case, that's why I used macro, so I don't have to write `-mode-hook`.

Comment: How do I make `m` evaluated before passing into the macro? Reading a bit more, the argument list is for making custom syntax, so there's really no way to evaluate.

Comment: Thanks. The function solution is neat. However, how to resolve the case with macro, where argument symbol is taken literally?

Comment: Maybe you could stick an eval there, but that would defeat the
purpose. Macro just isn't very appropriate for this task.

Comment: You are right. I think about it again, and I am expecting function-like behaviour but used macro. This is inappropriate. I should consider using macro when absolutely need to create a new syntax for reducing code duplicate or making DSL. Anyway, I follow the example in Emacswiki: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MacroBasics . Someone provides a more appropriate example.